# How can I change the position and timing a toast?

Tags: java, android

I am making a multiple choice quiz app and I would like to change the position and timing of my toast. I've looked at other answers and they didn't help because I did not make a toast instance variable. I am not sure if I should do that again because the app crashed when I did it the first time. Here is the code for one button:

```
 b_answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //check if the answer is correct
            if (b_answer1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(turn - 1).getName())) {
                score++;
                Toast.makeText(FlagQuizActivity.this, "Correct! Your score is: " + score, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                if (turn < list.size()) {
                    turn++;
                    newQuestion(turn);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(FlagQuizActivity.this, "You've finished the quiz! Your total score is: " + score, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(FlagQuizActivity.this, "Incorrect! Your score remains: " + score, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (turn < list.size()) {
                    turn++;
                    newQuestion(turn);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(FlagQuizActivity.this, "You've finished the quiz! Your total score is: " + score +"/50", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }

            }

        }
    });
```

How should I go about changing the position and length of the toast? the setGravity method made the app crash.

Comment: you can use custom toast

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getGravity() method as well as the setDuration() method. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast

Comment: these two methods should help with what you are trying to accomplish. If youd like for me to continue researching other paths lmk.